# In Codeigniter 2, how do I load a library into a global variable I can use in helper functions?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have the following files:

libraries/foo_library.php

helpers/foo_helper.php

views/main.php

Now my problem:
The library I've created is going to be used hundreds of times on each page load since it's used for determining the language and returning the correct item depending on the language stored in the database.

```
<?=$this->foo_library->language('English');?>
```

Now when used that way it works fine, though since I'm going to be using it for other language operations in the views, I created a few helper functions to make the views look cleaner

```
<?=sl('English words','Other language words')?>
```

Now this does work to an extent, though the **helper ends up creating a new object from the library every time the function is run** (Basically using the $CI =& get_instance() method to call the library).

This is a problem, since when you create the library, it saves data into memory so it doesn't need to keep querying the database. So **when the object gets recreated over and over again, it completely defeats the purpose**.

So I wanted to know, is there any clean way for my to create a library object that can be used anywhere in the project, including helper functions, and maintain it's persistence? (**The library does use the db builder class from CI**)

Answer (score 0):

You can autoload some elements on Codeigniter so you can access them globally

> The following items can be loaded automatically:
>
> Classes found in the libraries/ directory Helper files found in the
>   helpers/ directory Custom config files found in the config/ directory
>   Language files found in the system/language/ directory Models found in
>   the models/ folder

[Autoloader](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)

Comment: I tried that, though when calling the helper function from the view, it still recreated the actual library object each time, I'm not sure why though.
I also still had to do the get_instance() thing in the function, even though one would think it was still loaded from the view :(

Comment: The only thing i can think of is using some kind of Dependency Injection or IOC system for codeigniter. The purpose is to reuse objects. I really thought that the autoloader would do that for you in some ways.

Comment: Dependency Injection isn't a bad idea, will probably need to create an object to do that, so I'll end up going though like 5 objects to get to the library, but yeah, will see what I can do. Thanks